# How can I do an association analysis between “specific states” and “genotype frequency” of SNPs?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, model

I have 10 different states (0 to 9 - column6) for a list of SNPs (SNP C>T) and I wonder what is the relationship between these 10 states and the genotypic frequency of the SNPs [X_Heterozygous (column12), X_HomA(column13), X_HomB(column14)] for each state.

The idea is to answer the question: Which states are associated with higher or lower heterozygosity levels or with homozigous levels (allele A or B)?

If I have a variable number of SNPs in each state, and even sometimes I have no SNPs in some states. What kind of analysis should be recomended in this case? How can I do this in R?

Example of my dataset:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- "chr start tag depth BCV states alleles Number_of_Taxa Major_Allele_Frequency Minor_Allele_Frequency Number_Heterozygous X_Heterozygous X_HomA X_HomB
chr1 15759 chr1-15759 1 2 0 T 23 0.84783 0.15217 7 30.43 58.98 10.59
chr1 479528 chr1-479528 1 2 0 T 23 0.82609 0.17391 6 26.09 61.06 12.85
chr1 481655 chr1-481655 1 2 0 T 23 0.09091 0.90909 4 17.39 7.51 75.1
chr1 533396 chr1-533396 1 2 0 T 23 0.07143 0.92857 1 4.35 6.83 88.82
chr12 18140509 chr12-18140509 1 3 1 T 23 0.71739 0.28261 9 39.13 43.67 17.2
chr12 19052042 chr12-19052042 1 3 1 T 23 0.56522 0.43478 6 26.09 41.78 32.14
chr13 4356075 chr13-4356075 1 3 1 T 23 0.04348 0.95652 2 8.7 3.97 87.33
chr14 828824 chr14-828824 1 3 1 T 23 1 0 0 0 100 0
chr17 70573 chr17-70573 1 1 2 T 23 0.13043 0.86957 6 26.09 9.64 64.27
chr17 9490144 chr17-9490144 1 1 2 T 23 0.41304 0.58696 11 47.83 21.55 30.62
chr19 734649 chr19-734649 1 1 2 T 23 0.81818 0.18182 4 17.39 67.59 15.02
chr20 728701 chr20-728701 1 1 2 T 23 0.72727 0.27273 2 8.7 66.4 24.9
chr1 76739690 chr1-76739690 0 0 3 T 23 0.65217 0.34783 10 43.48 36.86 19.66
chr1 76739697 chr1-76739697 0 0 3 T 23 0.65217 0.34783 10 43.48 36.86 19.66
chr1 78257811 chr1-78257811 0 0 3 T 23 0.6087 0.3913 12 52.17 29.11 18.71
chr1 78754368 chr1-78754368 0 0 3 T 23 0.02174 0.97826 1 4.35 2.08 93.57
chr10 19490347 chr10-19490347 2 2 4 T 23 0.86364 0.13636 4 17.39 71.34 11.26
chr11 409967 chr11-409967 2 2 4 T 23 0.76087 0.23913 5 21.74 59.55 18.71
chr11 485587 chr11-485587 2 2 4 T 23 0.3913 0.6087 8 34.78 25.52 39.7
chr11 549433 chr11-549433 2 2 4 T 23 0.88636 0.11364 5 21.74 69.37 8.89
chr1 174872190 chr1-174872190 2 3 5 T 23 0.17391 0.82609 4 17.39 14.37 68.24
chr1 175303471 chr1-175303471 2 3 5 T 23 0.86957 0.13043 4 17.39 71.83 10.77
chr1 175303478 chr1-175303478 2 3 5 T 23 1 0 0 0 100 0
chr1 175378938 chr1-175378938 2 3 5 T 23 0.11905 0.88095 3 13.04 10.35 76.6
chr1 176982271 chr1-176982271 2 3 5 T 23 0.80952 0.19048 4 17.39 66.87 15.74
chr1 368141 chr1-368141 2 1 6 T 23 0.02381 0.97619 1 4.35 2.28 93.37
chr1 368252 chr1-368252 2 1 6 T 23 0.52273 0.47727 3 13.04 45.45 41.5
chr1 100362573 chr1-100362573 2 1 6 T 23 0.34091 0.65909 11 47.83 17.79 34.39
chr12 19252163 chr12-19252163 2 1 6 T 23 0.90909 0.09091 4 17.39 75.1 7.51
chr1 50668895 chr1-50668895 3 2 7 T 23 0.31818 0.68182 10 43.48 17.98 38.54
chr1 77320115 chr1-77320115 3 2 7 T 23 0.5 0.5 23 100 0 0
chr1 100376712 chr1-100376712 3 2 7 T 23 0.84091 0.15909 5 21.74 65.81 12.45
chr1 111731651 chr1-111731651 3 2 7 T 23 0.69565 0.30435 6 26.09 51.42 22.5
chr1 56703685 chr1-56703685 3 1 8 T 23 0.3913 0.6087 12 52.17 18.71 29.11
chr1 56703687 chr1-56703687 3 1 8 T 23 0.91304 0.08696 4 17.39 75.43 7.18
chr1 100402754 chr1-100402754 3 1 8 T 23 0.8913 0.1087 5 21.74 69.75 8.51
chr1 100403607 chr1-100403607 3 1 8 T 23 0.76087 0.23913 11 47.83 39.7 12.48
chr1 57049476 chr1-57049476 1 2 9 T 23 0.07143 0.92857 3 13.04 6.21 80.75
chr1 57198906 chr1-57198906 1 2 9 T 23 0.56522 0.43478 10 43.48 31.95 24.57
chr1 60265663 chr1-60265663 1 2 9 T 23 1 0 0 0 100 0
chr1 67715435 chr1-67715435 1 2 9 T 23 0.45455 0.54545 8 34.78 29.64 35.57"
dat <- read.table(text=data, header=T)
```

Comment: Be aware that "What kind of analysis should be recommended in this case?" is on topic here, but "How can I do this in R?" is not. You may get an answer to the former without an answer to the latter.

Comment: ok, thank you, no problem, I can find this  last answer in StackOverflow ;)